# "put one's attention on X" vs. "put one's attention to X"

Tags: prepositions

I wonder which form(s) are correct amongst the following:

- Someone put their attention **on** X.
- Someone put their attention **to** X.

Example:

> As a result of the rapid advancement of neural-network-based architectures and availability of large-scale datasets for question answering, researchers put their attention **to** building automatic question-answering systems.

Comment: researchers focused on x. or started focusing on. or started to focus on x.

Comment: It should be "turned their attention to building . . ."  The verb "put" is extremely awkward here, and I would venture to say it's non-native, or a google translate error.

Comment: @BillyKerr thanks, good point!

Answer (score -1):

In this case, "put their attention to" is correct; however, to make the sentence sound less passive, it may be better to use "attended to."

Comment: Thanks, is "put attention *on*" incorrect?

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt Yes, "put attention on" is incorrect, as the preposition "on" doesn't fit the given context.

Comment: Are you a native speaker? I have never heard anything like "put attention"!! I am a learner though!

Comment: I am indeed a native speaker. The reason you haven't heard of it is probably because the phrasing "put [their] attention to" is rather uncommon in everyday speech. While "put [their] attention to" technically isn't wrong, being the correct choice out of the two forms listed in the original post, it is definitely preferable to use "attended to."

Comment: Like Cardinal, I have never heard **put their attention to**. The expression I'm familiar with is **turned their attention to**. Google Books Ngram Viewer shows just a trace of **put attention to** and multiple examples of **turn attention to**.

Comment: to pay attention to something; to heed something; turn one's attention to. Put their attention to is incredibly awkward in English.

Answer (score -1):

I think *put one's attention **to** something* means to devote oneself to solving a problem, whereas *put one's attention **on** something* merely means to decide to pay attention to it.

So, "I decided to put my attention to the cat" would entail solving some problem related to the cat; "I decided to put my attention on the cat" could mean spending quality time with the cat.

Comment: I think this is a distinction not observed by many speakers, and one that cannot be depended on in interpreting another's words.

Comment: You may be right. I'm not sure I would say I "put my attention on" something—rather I "focused my attention on", "paid attention to", "devoted my attention to", "directed my intention to", etc. My intuition is that if I said I "put my attention to" something it would be to work hard at solving a problem, like "put my mind to" it. But a corpus search would be a good idea to investigate this.